# How do i disable a button after clicking it. In other words, have a button that is only clickable ONCE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an upgrade button for a game i am making, Obviously i want the upgrade to be available only once, how do i code this?

I looked around on the internet and every person suggested trying the following:

gameObject.GetComponent().interactable = false;

or

UpgradeButton.interactable = false;

or something of that sort. However this causes the button to be inactive from the start. I want it to be inactive after just one click.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not call this method / set the property from inside the button click event?

Comment: Did you try to set the `UpgradeButton.interactable = false;` in the button click event?

Comment: Where are you calling `.interactable`? Are you doing it in `Start()`?

Comment: you know how to disable a button and you know how to write code that executes when a button is clicked. Put 2 and 2 together and you have a button that is disabled when you click it. I don't know what more information we could provide.

Comment: Draco18s, yes its in the start()

Comment: It works now, the button stops being active after one click. The problem now is when i change to another scene and back the button becomes active again. Any possible solutions for this?

Comment: Side note: can you clarify why you explained one reason why button should be disabled (upgrade is available) but asking how to disable button on click? Those two things don't seem to be directly related...

Comment: Alexei beacause after the upgrade button is clicked, and thus the upgrade is unlocked, the player shouldnt be able to click the upgrade again with getting the same effect. Otherwise you can get the upgrade infinite times instead of just once.

Answer (score 1):

Set the property from the button's `onClick` method (where you probably want to have your upgrade code as well)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickExample : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button yourButton;

    void Start () {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick(){
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");
        yourButton.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

(from [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html))

Comment: Thank you i will try this, does it matter where in the script i put this?

Comment: It works now, the button stops being active after one click. The problem now is when i change to another scene and back the button becomes active again. Any possible solutions for this?

Comment: You need to store a variable (like `didPerformUpgrade`) over a scene load. Some possibilities how to achieve that are listed here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes

Answer (score 0):

To make your button inactive you need this line of code:

```
btn.interactable = false;
```

However, moving from one scene to another, everything will reset. Therefore, you need to save it's state. The easiest way to do it is with playerprefs:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("buttonState");
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState",0);
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("buttonState"))
```

The final code will look something like that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickExample : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button btn;
    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("buttonState")) // if the button was saved in memory
        {
           if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("buttonState") == 0) //if the value is 0
               btn.interactable = false; // make button disabled
        }
        else
        {
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState",1); // saving in memory that button is on
        }

    }

    public void buttonCliked(){
        btn.interactable = false; // making the button disabled
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState",0); //saving in memory that button is off 
    }

}
```

- Add this code to an Empty game object and then head to your button =>
  Button Script => OnClick
- Press on the little + sign and assign your empty game object (the one you had the script on)
- Select buttonCliked from the list you have.

Read more about playerprefs here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html